# Clear textbox history in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

how can I clear the history of a textbox? I have set autocomplet=off and set AutoCompleteType to Disabled. The history / text appears when I double click the textbox in Chrome / Firefox, so when I click it the text will be inserted in the textbox. Is there a way to stop this behaviour via ASP.NET / HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't work with autocomplete off, try to `change the textbox/input name (not the Id) to a random value` every time you load the page to the browser.

You can do it using javascript on window load as below:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("yourTextboxId").name = "txt"+ Math.random();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off auto-fill for a particular TextBox by setting autocomplete attribute value to off as shown below:

```
<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="TextBox1" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

or

You Can just write a textbox properties in Page_Prerender event in my page(codebehind).

protected void Page_PreRender(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
 TextBox1.Attributes.Add(“autocomplete”, “off”)
```

}

It should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to try on this line on your form

```
<form id="form2" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And there is also a  TextMode="password" if its confidential stuf that also doesnt save autocomplete I think.

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**After testing **autocomplete = "off"** inside *Input* and *form* elements and get nothing Reading [this Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) guide me to a new reality about how browsers dealing with auto-completion, So I tested suggestions and it seems this one working: Setting autocomplete="new-password" as advised:

> If you are defining a user management page where a user can specify a
>   new password for another person, and therefore you want to prevent
>   auto filling of password fields, you can use
>   **autocomplete="new-password"**; however, support for this value has not been implemented on Firefox.

Although I set non-password input elements to "new-value" and that is working too maybe for another suggestion in the article:

> In some cases, the browser will continue suggesting autocompletion
>   values even if the autocomplete attribute is set to off. This
>   unexpected behavior can be quite puzzling for developers. The trick to
>   really enforcing non-autocompletion is to assign an invalid value to
>   the attribute, for example:
>
> **autocomplete="nope"** Since this value is not a valid one for the
>   autocomplete attribute, the browser has no way to match it, and stops
>   trying to autocomplete the field.

Hope this help and useful for various scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.WEIGHT, new { autocomplete = "off" })%>
```

Answer (score -1):

As the other answerer said, disable AutoCompleteType property of the textbox.

Hide   Copy Code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
```

But this would not work in Mozilla Firefox. The best option would be to write a JavaScript onFocus of the text box to disable the autocomplete behaviour.

Hide   Copy Code

```
Javascript:
Hide   Copy Code
function disableautocompletion(id){ 
    var passwordControl = document.getElementById(id);
    passwordControl.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
}
```

Hope this helps!